Are mixed hodge structures sheaves on some stack?
For p-adic motives, it seems one should view F-crystals on $S$ as an approximation of motives over $S$. F-crystals on $S$ are sheaves on $S^{\Delta}$
For characteristic zero, mixed hodge are our approximations.
Is there a stack s.t perfect bundles on it are mixed hodge structures?
For example filtered $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces are sheaves on $A^1 /G_m$, so it's maybe not crazy to hope for such a thing. The hard part is how to view the lattice inside.

you should probably ask this on mathoverflow.net
